# Websocket Server in Node.js return RSV1 error when accessing from the phone APP

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket

In Node.js, I have implemented a WebSocket server which is used by a smartphone app. In some cases I got this kind of error (Invalid WebSocket frame: RSV1 must be clear):

[image]

This kind of application is running on many different servers across the world, but have the problem only with one instance. The app crashes randomly when using the communication between smartphones (Android or IOS) but it did not crash if I try to send messages over WebSocket using Java.

Looking at the doc of WebSocket specification have found that: 
[image]

Currently, I can't find what could be wrong. Do you think it could be some "network set-up issue"?

The libraries used for WebSocket in Node.js is ws 6.2.1.

The service is running inside a docker using alpine:8 image. As I told I have a problem only in one environment in all other environments everything works fine. Any idea what else to check?

Comment: does [this](https://github.com/websockets/ws/issues/1140) help in any way?

Comment: not so much.. :)

Comment: So that issue has no relevance to your question?

Comment: The problem here is that I got the error when accessing from the mobile app and no errors when accessing from Java app. Don't know what could be wrong.. (the app is developed by some external team (don't have source code to look at)).

Comment: Please read this https://github.com/websockets/ws/issues/1140 to understand the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Well in my case i was sending an object, when i JSON.stringify() it , it started working

Answer (score 0):

For my case I put in `return` and it solves my issue:

Before:

```js
if (pathname === "/foo/1") {
  wss.handleUpgrade(request, socket, head, function done(ws) {
    wss.emit("connection", ws, request);
  });
}
```

After:

```js
if (pathname === "/foo/1") {
  wss.handleUpgrade(request, socket, head, function done(ws) {
    wss.emit("connection", ws, request);
  });
  return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the RSV1 bit can be related to compression setting. There is a similar question to yours ("Invalid WebSocket frame: RSV1 must be clear) here: ["Error: Invalid WebSocket frame: RSV1 must be clear" while using Socket.IO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72186863/error-invalid-websocket-frame-rsv1-must-be-clear-while-using-socket-io/74794042#74794042)

All you need to do is on the server side, pass on an option related to the

> "Sec-WebSocket-Extensions: permessage-deflate;"

,

for example,

```js
new Server({
  perMessageDeflate {
   ...
  }
});
```